# Is there a package manager for emacs that can use git repositories directly?

Tags: package, package-repositories

Is there a way to manage packages in emacs where I can point to a git repository directly? (like [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) for eg).

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/emacscollective/borg or https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el can help.

Comment: or https://framagit.org/steckerhalter/quelpa

Comment: These seem like they could be posted as answers.

Comment: From personal experience I can second the hint by user:xuchunyang to the straight package manager.

Comment: I like use-package and I just found out that with quelpa-integration I also can install packages from GitHub `(use-package quelpa-use-package
  :ensure t)

(use-package bitwarden
  :ensure nil
  :quelpa (bitwarden
           :fetcher github
    :repo "seanfarley/emacs-bitwarden"))`

Comment: With Doom Emacs you can do something like that: https://github.com/dnlcorrea/doom-emacs/blob/cf5ae53f1123f9f1c4a04677c4501491496feeac/packages.el#L62

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several:

- Starting with Emacs 29 there is the built-in `package-vc-install` ([Fetching Package Sources (GNU Emacs Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fetching-Package-Sources.html))
- [Quelpa](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa)
  Quelpa allows for fetching packages from arbitrary sources and building them into a format that can be installed by package.el
- [Straight](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el)
  Install Emacs packages listed on MELPA, GNU ELPA, or Emacsmirror, or provide your own recipes. Packages are cloned as Git (or other) repositories.
- [Borg](https://github.com/emacscollective/borg)
  Assimilate Emacs packages as Git submodules.
- [El-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get)
  El-Get allows you to install and manage elisp code for Emacs. It supports lots of different types of sources and is able to install them, update them and remove them, but more importantly it will init them for you.

There is a [detailed comparison](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#comparison-to-other-package-managers) on the straight.el github page.

Comment: `straight` works very well, I'd recommend trying this one.